# setting text to clipboard in applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

Whenever i try to run the following code:

`set RAccounts to (read POSIX file "/Users/student/Desktop/Accounts.txt")
set word 1 of RAccounts to clipboard`

It gives me the error " cannot set text to clipboard " any help without having to do keystrokes etc. also when i try

`get word 1 of RAccounts and paste`

it tells me cannot make into type boolean any help guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are you trying to put word 1 into the clipboard.

```
set the clipboard to word 1 of RAccounts
```